# Указание пути к jpegtran в скрипте

Tags: perl

Добрый вечер!

Есть один скрипт - jpegrescan. Он использует в свою очередь jpegtran. Подскажите, как можно изменить скрипт таким образом, чтобы я мог указать сам путь к jpegtran, т.е.

```
perl.exe jpegrescan.pl Путь\jpegtran.exe in.jpg out.jpg
```

Код скрипта jpegrescan:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -ws
# jpegrescan by Loren Merritt
# Last updated: 2008-11-29 / Image Catalyst 2012-04-28
# This code is public domain.

sub jpegtran (@) {
    unless(system("jpegtran", $strip ? ("-copy","none") : ("-copy","all"), @_) == 0) {
        if ($? == -1) {
            die "Error execute jpegtran: $!\n";
        }
        elsif ($? & 128) {
            die sprintf(
                "jpegtran died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
                ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without'
            );
        }
        else {
            die "jpegtran exited with ERRORLEVEL=" . $? >> 8 . "\n";
        }
    }
}
# FIXME optimize order for either progressive transfer or decoding speed
sub canonize {
    my $txt = $prefix.$suffix.shift;

    $txt =~ s/\s*;\s*/;\n/g;
    $txt =~ s/^\s*//;
    $txt =~ s/ +/ /g;
    $txt =~ s/: (\d+) (\d+)/sprintf ": %2d %2d", $1, $2/ge;
    # treat u and v identically. I shouldn't need to do this, but with jpegtran overhead it saves 9% speed. cost: .008% bitrate.
    $txt =~ s/^2:.*\n//gm;
    $txt =~ s/^1:(.+)\n/1:$1\n2:$1\n/gm;
    # dc before ac, coarse before fine
    return join( "\n",
        sort {
            "$a\n$b" =~ /: *(\d+) .* (\d);\n.*: *(\d+) .* (\d);/ or die;
            !$3 <=> !$1 or $4 <=> $2 or $a cmp $b;
        }
        split( /\n/, $txt )
    );
}
sub try {
    my $txt = canonize(shift);
    my $rc;

#   print $txt, "\n\n"; # debug

    if (exists $memo{$txt}) {
        $rc = $memo{$txt};
    }
    else {
        open( my $io, "> $ftmp") or die "Error create $ftmp file: $!\n";

        print $io $txt;
        close $io;

        unlink $fout if (-f $fout);

        jpegtran("-scans", $ftmp, "-outfile", $fout, $jtmp);

        unless ($rc = -s $fout) {
            die "jpegtran output file zero size";
        }
        unless ($quiet) {
            print $verbose ? "$txt\n$rc\n\n" : ".";
        }
        $memo{$txt} = $rc;
    }

    return $rc;
}
sub triesn {
    my ($limit, @modes) = @_;
    my $overshoot = 0;
    my ($bmode, $bsize);

    foreach my $mode (@modes) {
        my $s = try($mode);

        if (!$bsize || $s < $bsize) {
            $bsize = $s;
            $bmode = $mode;
            $overshoot = 0;
        }
        elsif ($limit > 0 and ++$overshoot >= $limit) {
            last;
        }
    }
    return $bmode;
}
sub gen_modes {
    my $c = shift;
    my $str = shift;

    map {
        $_ => sprintf( "$c: 1 %d $str;$c: %d 63 $str;", $_, $_+1)
    } 2,5,8,12,18;
}
sub try_splits {
    my $c = shift;
    my $str = shift;
    my %n = gen_modes($c, $str);
    my $mode = triesn(2, "$c: 1 63 $str;", @n{2,8,5});

    if ($mode ne $n{8}) {
        return $mode;
    }
    else {
        return triesn(1, $mode, @n{12,18});
    }
}

sub get_stderr {
    my $code = shift;
    my $rc;

    if (ref $code eq 'CODE') {
        my $old_stderr;

        open $old_stderr, ">&", STDERR;
        open STDERR, ">", $otmp;
        $code->(@_);
        open STDERR, ">&", $old_stderr;
        $rc = do {
            local $/;

            open(my $io, $otmp);
            <$io>;
        };
                unlink( $otmp ) if (-f $otmp);

    }
    return $rc;
}

# sub main {
unless (scalar @ARGV == 2) {
    die "usage: jpegrescan in.jpg out.jpg\ntries various progressive scan orders\n";
}
$fin = $ARGV[0];
$fout = $ARGV[1];
$verbose = 0;
$quiet = 0;
$strip = 0;

$ftmp = "$fout-$$.scan";
$jtmp = "$fout-$$.jpg";
$otmp = "$fout-$$.out";

undef $/;
$|=1;

$old_size = -s $fin;

$prefix = "";
$suffix = "";

# convert the input to baseline, just to make all the other conversions faster
# FIXME there's still a bunch of redundant computation in separate calls to jpegtran
my $stderr = get_stderr(
    sub {
        jpegtran("-v", "-optimize", "-outfile", $jtmp, $fin);
    }   
);

if ($stderr =~ /components=(\d+)/) {
    my $rgb;

    if ($1 == 3) {
        $rgb = 1;
        # 012 helps very little
        # 0/12 and 0/1/2 are pretty evenly matched in frequency, but 0/12 wins in total size if every image had to use the same mode
        # dc refinement passes never help
        $dc = triesn(0, "0: 0 0 0 0;1: 0 0 0 0;2: 0 0 0 0;" );
        # jpegtran won't let me omit dc entirely, but I can at least quantize it away to make the rest of the tests faster.
        $prefix = "0 1 2: 0 0 0 9;";
    }
    elsif ($1 == 1) {
        $rgb = 0;
        $dc = "0: 0 0 0 0;";
        $prefix = "0: 0 0 0 9;";
    }
    else {
        die "File $fin is not RGB or grayscale\n"
    }

    foreach my $c ( 0 .. $rgb ) {
        my $max_i = $c ? 2 : 3;
        my $ml = "";
        my @modes;
        my $refine;

        foreach my $i ( 0 .. $max_i ) {
            push @modes, "$c: 1 8 0 $i;$c: 9 63 0 $i;".$ml;
            $ml .= sprintf("$c: 1 63 %d %d;", $i+1, $i);
        }
        $refine = triesn(1, @modes);
        $refine =~ s/.* (0 \d);//;
        $ac .= $refine . try_splits($c, $1);
    }

    # luma can make use of up to 3 refinement passes.
    # chroma can make use of up to 2 refinement passes.
    # refinement passes have some chance of being split (luma: 4%,4%,4%. chroma: 20%,8%) but the total bit gain is negligible.
    # msb pass should almost always be split (luma: 87%, chroma: 81%).
    # I have no theoretical reason for this list of split positions, they're just the most common in practice.
    # splitting into 3 ections is often slightly better, but the total number of bits saved is negligible.
    # FIXME: penalize lots of refinement passes because it's slower to decode. if so, then also force overwrite if bigger than the input.

    $prefix = "";
    %memo = ();
    $mode = $dc.$ac;
    $mode = canonize($mode);
    try($mode);
    $size = $memo{$mode};

    print "\n$mode\n$size\n" unless ($quiet);

    unlink(
        $jtmp,
        $ftmp,
        (($size >= $old_size) ? $fout : ())
    );
}
else {
    die "Invalud output from jpegtran\n";
}
```

Comment: А что мешает в %PATH% добавить путь к jpegtran?

Answer (score 1):

Что-то в духе:

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl -ws
  # jpegrescan by Loren Merritt
  # Last updated: 2008-11-29 / Image Catalyst 2012-04-28
  # This code is public domain.

  sub jpegtran (@) {\
    $jpegtran = shift;
    unless(system($jpegtran, $strip ? ("-copy","none") : ("-copy","all"), @_) == 0) {
        if ($? == -1) {
            die "Error execute $jpegtran: $!\n";
        }
        elsif ($? & 128) {
            die sprintf(
                "jpegtran died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
                ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without'
            );
        }
        else {
            die "$jpegtran exited with ERRORLEVEL=" . $? >> 8 . "\n";
        }
    }
  }
  # FIXME optimize order for either progressive transfer or decoding speed
  sub canonize {
    my $txt = $prefix.$suffix.shift;

    $txt =~ s/\s*;\s*/;\n/g;
    $txt =~ s/^\s*//;
    $txt =~ s/ +/ /g;
    $txt =~ s/: (\d+) (\d+)/sprintf ": %2d %2d", $1, $2/ge;
    # treat u and v identically. I shouldn't need to do this, but with jpegtran overhead it saves 9% speed. cost: .008% bitrate.
    $txt =~ s/^2:.*\n//gm;
    $txt =~ s/^1:(.+)\n/1:$1\n2:$1\n/gm;
    # dc before ac, coarse before fine
    return join( "\n",
        sort {
            "$a\n$b" =~ /: *(\d+) .* (\d);\n.*: *(\d+) .* (\d);/ or die;
            !$3 <=> !$1 or $4 <=> $2 or $a cmp $b;
        }
        split( /\n/, $txt )
    );
  }
  sub try {
    my $txt = canonize(shift);
    my $rc;

  #   print $txt, "\n\n"; # debug

    if (exists $memo{$txt}) {
        $rc = $memo{$txt};
    }
    else {
        open( my $io, "> $ftmp") or die "Error create $ftmp file: $!\n";

        print $io $txt;
        close $io;

        unlink $fout if (-f $fout);

        jpegtran("-scans", $ftmp, "-outfile", $fout, $jtmp);

        unless ($rc = -s $fout) {
            die "jpegtran output file zero size";
        }
        unless ($quiet) {
            print $verbose ? "$txt\n$rc\n\n" : ".";
        }
        $memo{$txt} = $rc;
    }

    return $rc;
  }
  sub triesn {
    my ($limit, @modes) = @_;
    my $overshoot = 0;
    my ($bmode, $bsize);

    foreach my $mode (@modes) {
        my $s = try($mode);

        if (!$bsize || $s < $bsize) {
            $bsize = $s;
            $bmode = $mode;
            $overshoot = 0;
        }
        elsif ($limit > 0 and ++$overshoot >= $limit) {
            last;
        }
    }
    return $bmode;
  }
  sub gen_modes {
    my $c = shift;
    my $str = shift;

    map {
        $_ => sprintf( "$c: 1 %d $str;$c: %d 63 $str;", $_, $_+1)
    } 2,5,8,12,18;
  }
  sub try_splits {
    my $c = shift;
    my $str = shift;
    my %n = gen_modes($c, $str);
    my $mode = triesn(2, "$c: 1 63 $str;", @n{2,8,5});

    if ($mode ne $n{8}) {
        return $mode;
    }
    else {
        return triesn(1, $mode, @n{12,18});
    }
  }

  sub get_stderr {
    my $code = shift;
    my $rc;

    if (ref $code eq 'CODE') {
        my $old_stderr;

        open $old_stderr, ">&", STDERR;
        open STDERR, ">", $otmp;
        $code->(@_);
        open STDERR, ">&", $old_stderr;
        $rc = do {
            local $/;

            open(my $io, $otmp);
            <$io>;
        };
                unlink( $otmp ) if (-f $otmp);

    }
    return $rc;
  }

  # sub main {
  unless (scalar @ARGV == 3) {
    die "usage: jpegrescan jpegtran_with_fullpath in.jpg out.jpg\ntries various progressive scan orders\n";
  }
    $jpegtran_with_path = $ARGV[0];
    $fin = $ARGV[1];
  $fout = $ARGV[2];
  $verbose = 0;
  $quiet = 0;
  $strip = 0;

  $ftmp = "$fout-$$.scan";
  $jtmp = "$fout-$$.jpg";
  $otmp = "$fout-$$.out";

  undef $/;
  $|=1;

  $old_size = -s $fin;

  $prefix = "";
  $suffix = "";

  # convert the input to baseline, just to make all the other conversions faster
  # FIXME there's still a bunch of redundant computation in separate calls to jpegtran
  my $stderr = get_stderr(
      sub {
          jpegtran($jpegtran_with_path, "-v", "-optimize", "-outfile", $jtmp, $fin);
      }   
  );

  if ($stderr =~ /components=(\d+)/) {
      my $rgb;

      if ($1 == 3) {
          $rgb = 1;
          # 012 helps very little
          # 0/12 and 0/1/2 are pretty evenly matched in frequency, but 0/12 wins in total size if every image had to use the same mode
          # dc refinement passes never help
          $dc = triesn(0, "0: 0 0 0 0;1: 0 0 0 0;2: 0 0 0 0;" );
          # jpegtran won't let me omit dc entirely, but I can at least quantize it away to make the rest of the tests faster.
          $prefix = "0 1 2: 0 0 0 9;";
      }
      elsif ($1 == 1) {
          $rgb = 0;
          $dc = "0: 0 0 0 0;";
          $prefix = "0: 0 0 0 9;";
      }
      else {
          die "File $fin is not RGB or grayscale\n"
      }

      foreach my $c ( 0 .. $rgb ) {
          my $max_i = $c ? 2 : 3;
          my $ml = "";
          my @modes;
          my $refine;

          foreach my $i ( 0 .. $max_i ) {
              push @modes, "$c: 1 8 0 $i;$c: 9 63 0 $i;".$ml;
              $ml .= sprintf("$c: 1 63 %d %d;", $i+1, $i);
          }
          $refine = triesn(1, @modes);
          $refine =~ s/.* (0 \d);//;
          $ac .= $refine . try_splits($c, $1);
      }

      # luma can make use of up to 3 refinement passes.
      # chroma can make use of up to 2 refinement passes.
      # refinement passes have some chance of being split (luma: 4%,4%,4%. chroma: 20%,8%) but the total bit gain is negligible.
      # msb pass should almost always be split (luma: 87%, chroma: 81%).
      # I have no theoretical reason for this list of split positions, they're just the most common in practice.
      # splitting into 3 ections is often slightly better, but the total number of bits saved is negligible.
      # FIXME: penalize lots of refinement passes because it's slower to decode. if so, then also force overwrite if bigger than the input.

      $prefix = "";
      %memo = ();
      $mode = $dc.$ac;
      $mode = canonize($mode);
      try($mode);
      $size = $memo{$mode};

      print "\n$mode\n$size\n" unless ($quiet);

      unlink(
          $jtmp,
          $ftmp,
          (($size >= $old_size) ? $fout : ())
      );
  }
  else {
      die "Invalud output from jpegtran\n";
  }
```